# jQuery datepicker, dialog - scroll to a location of date picked

Tags: dialog, scroll, datepicker

Problem: scroll to a specific location in a jQuery dialog

I have a datepicker inline on my site which shows the present month calendar.
If the user clicks on any of the dates I am showing a list of calendar events coming from a Feed.

The code is as below:

```
<div id="datepicker" style="font: 80% 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;"></div>
                            <script  type="text/javascript">
                                var caldate;
                                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
                                $("#datepicker").change(function() {
                                    caldate = $(this).val(); 

                                    $("#dialog").dialog({
                                        bgiframe: true,
                                        maxHeight: 450,
                                        width: 600,
                                        modal: true,
                                        draggable: true,
                                        resizable: false,
                                        position: 'center',
                                        show: { effect: "fade", duration: 600 },
                                        hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 600 }
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
                            <div id="dialog" title="Calendar Events">DisplayFeed("Calendar Events")</div>
```

DisplayFeed retrieves data from a html helper class and the data is show properly.

Now the hurdle is when the user selects a particular date in datepicker inline.
I need to scroll to the events occurring on a selected date from the list in dialog.

I tried to get the html inside the div dialog. Where as I am getting the error as undefined when I try document.getElementByID("#dialog").innerHTML to compare the dater with caldate captured during the selection.

Any idea's to put me in the correct direction would be of a great help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by adding a special div ID generated by event date (Convert date to Linux time stamp and added to div as ID), For each event.

Then scrolling to the event occurring on the selected date, by converting the selected date to Linux time stamp and using `document.getElementById(linuxtimestamp.toString()).scrollIntoView()` in javascript.